# How to refresh css when sass compiles

Tags: sass, page-refresh

Up to now I have used codekit to compile sass also it has the auto reload feature. Now because I wanted to take advantage of sourcemaps with sass, I needed to use the terminal instead of codekit to compile sass

```
sass --watch --sourcemap --compass sass:stylesheets
```

This is because codekit does not support sourcemaps. Is there any app of script I could use to auto reload the browser when sass compiles?

Thanks

Comment: Is something wrong with F5?

Comment: as i remember,  [prepros](https://prepros.io) support sourcemaps ...